# Execute default command on tilda terminal startup

Tags: bash, terminal, command-line-interface, startupscript

I'm using expressvpn and they offer a terminal command `expressvpn connect` to connect to the latest vpn. Sometimes i forget to execute the command on startup and i'd like it to be automatically executed in tilda.

[Tilda](https://github.com/lanoxx/tilda) is a dropdown terminal for linux im using.
Furthermore i'm using ubuntu 16.04 and i have managed to put tilda in the autostart so it starts with the system.

**Question:** How can i make tilda on startup execute the simple command `expressvpn connect`?
I have not found any such option in the preferences of tilda.

Thanks for your help!

Muff

Comment: Have you considered putting the connection command into a `bash` script and have that autoexecute?

Comment: yes but doesn't this execute the command in a standard terminal and not tilda? i must admit i've never written any bash script before.

Comment: You can create a desktop file which can be used to directly call Tilda and execute a script, then put the desktop file into autostart.  Have a look here for info: http://askubuntu.com/questions/436891/create-a-desktop-file-that-opens-and-execute-a-command-in-a-terminal